# Как можно динамически менять Title на странице силами JS?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Есть такая задача: когда происходит некоторое событие (скролл страницы), необходимо менять title.
Мне нужно, чтобы происходила такая магия: я скроллю страничку (соответственно, координата Y будет меняться) и при этом, при смене координаты, я хочу чтобы менялся и тайтл. Возможно ли это сделать каким-либо известным науке способом?

Я пытался использовать конструкцию вида

```
document.title = window.scrollY;
```

Но она отрабатывает корректно только когда я использую таймаут: загружаю страницу, скроллю её (скроллю руками), жду одну секунду, меняю тайтл.

```
function setNewTitle() {
  document.title = window.scrollY;
}

setTimeout(setNewTitle, 1000);
```

Мне, по сути, нужно сделать то же самое, только без таймаута. Идеальный вариант - скроллим, координата сразу меняется, тайтл сразу меняется.

Comment: "пытался использовать конструкцию вида" - когда?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event

Comment: document.addEventListener("scroll", function() { document.title = window.scrollY; }) не это хотите достичь?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
document.onscroll = () => {
    document.title = window.scrollY;
    output.innerText = window.scrollY;
}
```

```css
body {
    height: 1000vh;
}

p {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<p>Scroll Y: <b id="output"></b></p>
```